# Regex to match URLs and exclude those in <a> and <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular, regex

I'm trying to match URLs but excluding those within `<a>` and `<img>` tags.

`/(?!(?!.<a)[^<].*<\/a>)([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/ig`

The problem is that it match the url within `<img>` if it's not in `<a>` tag

For example:

1. `<a href="https://google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Google</a>` **NOT MATCH (Correct)**
2. google.com **MATCH (Correct)**
3. `<a href="google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"></a>` **NOT MATCH (Correct)**
4. `<p>https://google.com</p>` **MATCH (Correct)**
5. `<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png">` **MATCH (WRONG)**

What should I add o remove to my Regex?

Comment: Just remove the unwanted elements before you use the regex.

Comment: @Andreas I just want to replace the urls that are not inside the tags but keeping the others inside the tags

Comment: (Parse the string) Grab the elements, remove anything that isn't a text node or doesn't match your regex, replace the text node with whatever you want instead of the URI/text -> done